# How to append the suffix to be unique if there is a record with the same name in the database?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, .net-core

I'm in trouble with a little problem.

products are listed in the database. In the code column, the data is kept as follows:

> "F-01, F-02, F-03, ..., X-99"

Customers may want to add external data to the system, but sometimes they want to add the same record.

To avoid these duplicates, I need to put a distinctive suffix like "-01" at the end of the line of code column.

I am developing this system in c # and I have developed such a logic:

```
int counter = 1;
var code = "F-" + productEntity.Code;
​
while (await uow.Repository<Product>().Query().AnyAsync(a => a.Code == code) == true)
{
   code = code + "-" + counter;
   counter++;
}
```

But what I noticed is that a record I added in the form of **F-01-1** will turn into **F-01-1-1** when it comes back to me.

I think I missed a very small point, but I can not reach my goal.

Comment: This logic will never end to give you problems. What about splitting the three information in three different columns and only when you need to display the _code_ you join that info together?

Comment: this is not possible because I'm developing on a running system. I wish I had it.

Comment: You just need to keep a base code value and always construct `code` from `baseCode` and `counter` instead of accumulating counters at the end of `code`.

Comment: i dont unterstand actually your comment. can you explain a little more?

Comment: The line `code = code + '-' + counter;` is adding `"-1"` to `"F-01"` instead of starting with "F" and adding the next value in the sequence. You need a base value, such as `"F"`, and then assign code to that plus the next counter value.

Comment: Tip to the wise.  If this is used by multiple people it is better to pick a random number, then see if it is in use, than it is to just increment and hope.  Increment and hope causes race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `code + "-" + counter;` appends 3 strings together and return the result.

Say:

- `code` is `"F-01"`
- `counter` is `1`

Then the expression above will be evaluated as such:

- `"F-01" + "-" + "1"`, that is `"F-01-1"`

If you reexecute your method, then the expression will be:

- `"F-01-1" + "-" + "1"` that is `"F-01-1-1"`

And so on.

**The solution** is to split the code to extract the last part, which corresponds to the value of the counter. It is done with `string[] parts = "F-01-1".Split('-')`:

- `parts[0] = "F"`
- `parts[1] = "01"`
- `parts[2] = "1"` which corresponds to the counter

So now `int counter = int.Parse(parts[2]) + 1` will return the next value for counter `2`.

And you can have your full code `"F-01-2"` returned by `code = $"{parts[0]}-{parts[1]}-{counter}"`